# Is there a function to get post info for any publish_status by post ID?

Tags: posts, wp-query, database

I'm trying to, essentially, check whether a post exists and if it does (in published, draft or auto-draft states) return the post info. I'm finding `get_post()` doesn't seem to work with drafts, and `get_posts()` doesn't allow me to specify the specific post ID I'm looking for.

Is there a function to get post info for any `publish_status` by post ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the codex that would suggest that [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) would not work with drafts.
if you experience otherwise, try [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) with the `include` or [`post__in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters) parameter.

Also see the supported type and status parameters [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters).